# How to draw route on apple map in swift using google direction API?

Tags: ios, swift, google-api, apple-maps

Below response I am getting from google direction api. Now I need to draw step by step route on apple map.

```swift
let directionURL = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?key=\(samplekey)s&origin=valsad&destination=rajkot"
let parameters = [String: String]()

SCMServiceManager().createSmartServiceWith(params: parameters , url: directionURL, httpMethod:kHTTPMethodGET ) { (url, result, error) in

    guard let responseDict = result as? [String:Any] else { return }

    let status = responseDict["status"] as! String
    var routesArray:String!
    if status == "OK" {
        routesArray = (((responseDict["routes"]!as! [Any])[0] as! [String:Any])["overview_polyline"] as! [String:Any])["points"] as? String
        print("routesArray: \(String(describing: routesArray))")
}
```

I can post some json response as well if required. Thanks. I am using apple map in my app.

Comment: Both Apple map and Google map are different. So the data given by direction api will not accurately work on Apple map, I think.

Comment: Bad news for me i think.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you use this library for drawing a route. https://github.com/raphaelmor/Polyline